# switch depending on value inside function

Tags: java, switch-statement

I have a one-character string `ch`, and I want to return some integer depending of its value. I managed to make this `if else` statement using the regular expressions method .regex:

```
if (ch.matches("[AEILNORSTU]")){
            return 1;
        } else if (ch.matches("[DG]")){
            return 2;
        } else if (ch.matches("[BCMP]")){
            return 3;
        } else if (ch.matches("[FHVWY]")){
            return 4;
        } else if (ch.matches("[K]")){
            return 5;
        } else if (ch.matches("[JX]")){
            return 8;
        } else if (ch.matches("[QZ]")){
            return 10;
        } else return 0;
```

Is there a `switch` equivalent to this?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Doesn't look like a real duplicate...

Comment: @assylias Alright let me find you something else.

Comment: @assylias How about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31497818/switches-in-java-can-i-include-a-condition-in-a-case)?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis my point being that in this case, a series of `case "A": case "E": case "I":` etc. could work - or a hashmap of coerespondences, or an `int[26]`. This would not work for a more complex regex.

Comment: @assylias Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873590/in-java-using-switch-statement-with-a-range-of-value-in-each-case) perhaps.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis getting there ;-)

Comment: @assylias [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774446/how-to-do-a-case-with-multiple-conditions)? That's all I'm going to look for. It's on you now.

Comment: FYI, you can use `"AEILNORSTU".contains(ch)` instead of `ch.matches("[AEILNORSTU]"`.

Comment: @shmosel thanks, `contains` suits better this problem