# How can I write several conditions in a switch case to have same behavior?

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

`switch (x)`
`{`
`case A:`
`case B:`
`case C:`
  `.doSomething()`
`}`
Is there a way I could have those 3 cases in one line? For example something like this
`case A, B, C:`?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: whatever u have written that will do the same as u want.

Comment: Yes: `case A: case B: case C:`, the three in the **same** line.

Comment: @Reimeus Nothing really I'm just curious if it's possible. For example when declaring integer values, you could have     `int x`    `int y`    `int z`etc.    or you could have    `int x, y, z`    I'm just wondering if that's possible with cases.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086322/java-switch-statement-multiple-cases

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aside from removing the line breaks and putting those `case`s all on the same line, no.

You will have to have three `case` keywords and three `:`'s.

If you want details, see [section 14.11 in the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11). In particular:

```
SwitchLabel:
    case ConstantExpression :
    case EnumConstantName :
    default :
```

There is no pattern in the grammar that would accept something like `case A,B,C:` for a *SwitchLabel*.

It is a common practice, though, to structure cases as in your example when multiple cases do the same thing:

```
switch (value) {
case 1:
case 3:
case 5:
    System.out.println("It's a positive odd number less than 7!"); 
    break;
case 4:
case 8:
    System.out.println("It's a multiple of 4 between 1 and 9!");
    break;
default:
    System.out.println("It's just another boring number.");
    break;
}
```

Java programmers will generally get a clear understanding of code like that when they read it. Putting multiple cases on a single line (i.e. no line break) is much less common and will not be as clearly understood at a glance by a typical programmer (who would probably just think you accidentally deleted a line break).

Answer (score 1):

Not the way you suggest, but you can do this (from the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)):

```
class SwitchDemo2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int month = 2;
        int year = 2000;
        int numDays = 0;

        switch (month) {
            case 1: case 3: case 5:
            case 7: case 8: case 10:
            case 12:
                numDays = 31;
                break;
            case 4: case 6:
            case 9: case 11:
                numDays = 30;
                break;
            case 2:
                if (((year % 4 == 0) && 
                     !(year % 100 == 0))
                     || (year % 400 == 0))
                    numDays = 29;
                else
                    numDays = 28;
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid month.");
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("Number of Days = "
                           + numDays);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> For example when declaring integer values, you could have int x int y int zetc. or you could have int x, y, z I'm just wondering if that's possible with cases.

That is a complete different question and it is possible depending on what you are doing.

You can have nested switches like

```
switch(x) {
      case 1:
          switch(y) {
               case 2:
                    switch(z) {
                        case 3:
```

Or you can use a formula provided you know the range of possible values like this

```
switch(x * 100 + y * 10 + z) {
    case 123: // x = 1, y = 2, z = 3
```

obviously this assumes x, y, z are between [0..9]