# Fully utilizing a switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

My Java textbook asked me about the following error:

```
switch (score)
        {
            case (score > 90):
                grade = 'A';
                break;
            case (score > 80):
                grade = 'B';
                break;
            default:
                grade = 'C';
        }
```

I already know where the error is:

- Switch statements aren't built for comparisons like `(score > 90)`; that's for if/else statements.

But this got me wondering: How *could* a switch statement efficiently account for ranges of integers?

The most obvious example I could think of is below, but I find it rather brute-force:

```
switch (score)
    {
        case 90: case 91: case 92: case 94: case 95:
        case 96: case 97: case 98: case 99: case 100:
            grade = 'A';
            break;
        case 80: case 81: case 82: case 84: case 85:
        case 86: case 87: case 88: case 89:
            grade = 'B';
            break;
        default:
            grade = 'C';
    }
```

How else could a concept like this be expressed in a switch statement?

Comment: Why aren't you allowed to use `if-else`?

Comment: There's no other way of doing that with a switch statement. That's why you use an if statement :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java switch statement multiple cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086322/java-switch-statement-multiple-cases)

Comment: @Mark your question is unclear to me: from your code example it seems that you already know what a switch statement can and can't do. So in the case above you obviously *should not* use it because you're dealing with ranges. When you'll deal with exact values then it may be proper to use switch/case.

Comment: The brute force method actually won't work!

What happens if someone has a score that is 92.4?

Comment: @Marcin: Good point in general, but the OP did not imply that `score` is `float` or `double`.

Comment: Thank you for all your responses! 
Because we all agree if/else is simply the way to go, the point of my question was to understand what ways a switch statement could still replicate the same approach. While not only serving as great examples of *why* if/else is superior, the answers below are also exemplify creative approaches that will likely prove useful down the road.

Comment: In general, when I see myself using a switch statement, my next thought is "how should I refactor this to not use a switch".  Often with a switch some refactor is a better solution.  That being said, it does not address your specific question.

Comment: Not a duplicate post. The point of this question was to find how one could still utilize a switch statement for this purpose regardless of the efficiency of if/else statements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you take advantage of the fact that grades change with every change of `10` in the score, and assuming that `score` is an integer data type, then you can divide by `10` to eliminate most cases:

```
switch (score / 10)
{
    case 9:
    case 10:
        grade = 'A';
        break;
    case 8:
        grade = 'B';
        break;
    default:
        grade = 'C';
}
```

If there is no such rule (if the "grade" bucket sizes are differing and arbitrary), then the best you can do is if/else-if/else statements.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: it can't.
The long answer: The switch statement cannot accept expressions like this since switch statements operate on single values of a variable rather than a range of variables like you've shown.

Answer (score 1):

May be not a best answer but very simple approach can be

```
int temp;

if(score > 90) 
 temp = 1;
else if(score > 80) 
 temp = 2;


switch (temp)
        {
            case (1):
                grade = 'A';
                break;
            case (2):
                grade = 'B';
                break;
            default:
                grade = 'C';
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This version I just made could be deemed more elegant:

```
 int score_new = score/10 

\\This gets you the first digit.. make sure score_new is int and not double

switch (score_new)

{
   case 10: case 9:
        grade = 'A';
        break;        
    case 8:
        grade = 'B';
        break;
    default:
        grade = 'C';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In some programming languages something like this

```
switch (true) {
  case (0 <= val &&  val < 1000): /* do something */ break;
  case (1000 <= val &&  val < 2000): /* do something */ break;
  ...
  case (29000 <= val &&  val < 30000): /* do something */ break;
}
```

is possible but first it's not very performant and second java doesn't accept that. So use if-then-else:

```
 int val = 500;
 if (0 <= val &&  val < 1000){ System.out.println("Test");}
 else if (1000 <= val &&  val < 2000){ /* do something */}
 else if (29000 <= val &&  val < 30000){ /* do something */}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case, `if` statement is better and readable. `switch` statement is good for small set of `int` or `enum` values.

Answer (score -1):

In Java, a `switch` statement can only test `int` values (since Java 1.0), enum values (since Java 5.0), and String values (since Java 7.0), and only be able to test for equality. Note that `byte`, `short`, and `char` can be upcasted to `int`. But `long`, `float`, and `double` values cannot be tested.

Legal examples:

```
int x = (...);
switch (x) {
    case 0: (...)
}

byte x = (...);
switch (x) {
    case 0: (...)
}

String x = (...);
switch (x) {
   case "a": (...)
}
```

Illegal examples:

```
long x = (...);
switch (x) {
    case 0: (...)
}

double x = (...);
switch (x) {
    case 0.0: (...)
}
```

Comment: The question was: "How else could a concept like this be expressed in a switch statement?"