# Write an if..else statement with a switch statement in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

How can I write this if..else statement with a switch statement in JavaScript?

```
var hour = new Date().getHours();
var msg = "";
if (hour >= 0 && hour < 6) {
    msg = "بامداد شما بخیر !";
} else if (hour >= 6 && hour < 11) {
    msg = "صبح شما بخیر !";
} else if (hour >= 11 && hour < 15) {
    msg = "ظهر شما بخیر !";
} else if (hour >= 15 && hour < 20) {
    msg = "عصر شما بخیر !";
} else if (hour >= 20 && hour < 24) {
    msg = "شب شما بخیر !";
} else {
    msg = "ساعت وارد شده نامعتبر است !";
}
print(hour);
print("------------------------");
print(msg);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java switch statement multiple cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086322/java-switch-statement-multiple-cases)

Answer (score 3):

Since `hour` has just 24 discrete values, you could just handle all of them in a switch-case:

```
switch (hour) {
case 0:
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
case 4:
case 5:
    msg = "بامداد شما بخیر !";
    break;
case 6:
case 7:
case 8:
case 9:
case 10:
    msg = "صبح شما بخیر !";
    break;
case 11:
case 12:
case 13:
case 14:
    msg = "ظهر شما بخیر !";
    break;
case 15:
case 16:
case 17:
case 18:
case 19:
    msg = "عصر شما بخیر !";
    break;
default:
    msg = "شب شما بخیر !";
}
```

But honestly, isn't a wasted effort. Using if-else is much more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just say at the outset that I *wouldn't* rewrite it as a `switch`. But I would definitely change it. (I'll do the `switch` below, though.)

First, your `"ساعت وارد شده نامعتبر است !"` case will never happen. `getHours` returns a number between 0 and 23, inclusive. So there's no need to handle the case of `< 0` or `>= 24`.

Here's how I'd write it:

```
var hour = new Date().getHours();
var msg;
if (hour < 6) {
    msg = "بامداد شما بخیر !";
} else if (hour < 11) {
    msg = "صبح شما بخیر !";
} else if (hour < 15) {
    msg = "ظهر شما بخیر !";
} else if (hour < 20) {
    msg = "عصر شما بخیر !";
} else {
    msg = "شب شما بخیر !";
}
print(hour);
print("------------------------");
print(msg);
```

Note how we're not having to write our limits in two places. There's no need for it, since we won't evaluate later `else if`s if the earlier `if` was true.

Now, for the actual `switch`, we do something similar, using the fact that JavaScript's `switch` is more powerful than in many similar-looking languages (JavaScript's `switch` is basically just an `if/else if`):

```
var hour = new Date().getHours();
var msg;
switch (true) {
    case hour < 6:
        msg = "بامداد شما بخیر !";
        break;
    case hour < 11:
        msg = "صبح شما بخیر !";
        break;
    case hour < 15:
        msg = "ظهر شما بخیر !";
        break;
    case hour < 20:
        msg = "عصر شما بخیر !";
        break;
    default:
        msg = "شب شما بخیر !";
        break;
}
print(hour);
print("------------------------");
print(msg);
```

How that works: JavaScript's `switch` allows the `case` labels to be *expressions*. It evaluates each `case` *in source code order* against the value you give in the `switch`, taking the first case that matches. If no cases match, it uses the `default` (regardless of where the default is in the source code).

Again: I wouldn't do that. But the question was *how* to do it. :-)