# Scanner problems in switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

I tried to add a switch statement in a method then put that method in another switch statement. It didn't work out as I expected it to... **When I execute the program, the console wants me to immediately add a user input, which is not what I had in mind.**

Here is what shows up in the console after I've executed the program:

> qwerty
>
> Greetings, dear Pilgrim. What is thine name?
>
> Bob
>
> Hello, Bob. Is thou ready to start thine quest? [Yes or No]
>
> Please use capital letters... [Yes or No]

**Application code**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class rolePlay {

    static Scanner player = new Scanner(System.in);
    static String system;
    static String choice = player.nextLine();

    public void letterError() {
        System.out.println("Please use capital letters...");
        System.out.println(system);

        switch (choice) {

        case "Yes" : System.out.println("May thine travels be shadowed upon by Talos...");
        break;
        case "No" : System.out.println("We shall wait for thee...");
        break;
        default: 
        break;
        }
    }
    public rolePlay() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        rolePlay you = new rolePlay();

        System.out.println("Greetings, dear Pilgrim. What is thine name?");
        String charName = player.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Hello, " + charName + ". Is thou ready to start thine quest?");

        system = "[Yes or No]";
        System.out.println(system);
        //String choice = player.nextLine();

        switch (choice) {

        case "Yes" : System.out.println("May thine travels be shadowed upon by Talos...");
        break;
        case "No" : System.out.println("We shall wait for thee...");
        break;
        default : you.letterError();
        break;
        }

        player.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java switch statement multiple cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086322/java-switch-statement-multiple-cases)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static String choice = player.nextLine();
```

This line will only be called once, when the class is first accessed. That's why it wants a user input immediately. You need to call `player.nextLine()` at the time you want to get user input; in this case, you should call it before each switch statement, like in the line you commented out.

Comment: You may add the reason and explain why this behaves like that (`static`).

Answer (score 0):

Calling `player.nextLine()` and assigning it to your static variable `choice` causes the problem. Static variables are retrieved when the class is first called on, which in your case means before the main method is called. You should instead not assign a value to `choice` and assign `player.nextLine()` to `choice` inside of the main method when you're expecting the user to input something to console.

```
    System.out.println("Greetings, dear Pilgrim. What is thine name?");
    String charName = player.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Hello, " + charName + ". Is thou ready to start thine quest?");

    system = "[Yes or No]";
    System.out.println(system);
    choice = player.nextLine();
```

should look like that after you remove `player.nextLine()` from the `Static String choice` declaration.

Comment: This only partially solves the problem. There should be another `choice = player.nextLine();` before the switch in `letterError` or it'll just use the stored choice again (which will hit the default case and do nothing).